# VLC and all main Ubuntu sofwares are unauthenticated

Tags: 10.04, apt, package-management, vlc, mplayer

Then how I'll install all these software including VLC and Mplayer in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.?

Comment: Could you paste the message you are getting into your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your Ubuntu version, I guess this version is not supported now.

Open up Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-pulse mozilla-plugin-vlc
```

Additionally you can also install it using Synaptic or by building the binary yourself.

For details: [VLC for Ubuntu](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS is still supported.